# Make AVURLAsset playable offline with AVAssetCache

Tags: avfoundation, avplayer, offline-caching, avurlasset

AVURLAsset has property assetCache of type AVAssetCache, which has property playableOffline, that indicates if AVAsset is available to be played without a network connection.

Property playableOffline is readonly, so the question how is it possible to make this property to be YES?

The purpose is to automatically store audio assets once loaded from network.

Comment: If you're trying to cache streaming media and property playableOffline is equal to false it's because of a copyright protection.

Comment: @ninjaproger very interesting, thank you for answer, but actually I faced, that the property assetCache always nil, and I can't figure out how configure asset to make assetCache not to be nil

Comment: @DmitriyStupivtsev IF YOU FIND ANY SOLUTION , PLEASE SHOW HERE TOO...

Comment: @Vats I'm sorry, actually, I skipped this issue as I didn't find solution and started most important tasks

Comment: @DmitriyStupivtsev, No prob. i've found a https://github.com/neekeetab/CachingPlayerItem library that helps me to  do so.